# OOP inheritance Selenium Get Title method with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, selenium, oop

In Class Step1, I configured the ChromeDriver
And Navigate URL

[Picture for clarification with the code Step1 Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ar9l.png)

Then I created another class [step3 ] to get the page title

[Picture for clarification with the code Step3 Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaQEL.png)

I created an inheritance between them, but there is a problem

I don't know well what the problem is, I have attached a picture of the problem

If I request the title From Step3 Class gets a new instance And it opens a new page

Please help.. I searched for other sources and didn't get anything

Thank you all

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAk4Y.png)

Step1 Class code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Public Class Step1
    Public driver As ChromeDriver
    Public Shared options As ChromeOptions
    Public Shared service As ChromeDriverService
    Public Sub New()
        options = New ChromeOptions
        options.AddArgument("--lang=en-us")
        options.AddArgument("--window-size=400,700")
        options.AddAdditionalChromeOption("useAutomationExtension", False)
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", False)
        service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        driver = New ChromeDriver(service, options)
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartNavigate()
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Step3 Class code

```
Public Class step3
    Inherits Step1
    Public Sub GetTitle()
        Try
            MsgBox(driver.Title)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please don't attach pictures of code.  Screenshots of your application are great, but would really benefit if you could add in an English translation.  You probably also need to explain what exactly the problem is and how it differs from expectations

Comment: that's nice of you GetTitle() method not worked in class name step3 
if i delete class name step3 and add this method to class name step1
its woked 100% But I want to apply the concept of inheritance

Comment: Just so I’m 100% clear.  When you are creating an instance of Step3 it’s starting a new browser window/tab.  That is the issue?

Comment: yes bro this is problem

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new instance of Step3 you also create a new Selenium-Driver and therefor a new browser-window.
If you only want one browser you have to make the driver shared

```
Public Shared driver As ChromeDriver
```

and then in Sub new:

```
 Public Sub New()
       If driver isnot nothing then return

        options = New ChromeOptions
        options.AddArgument("--lang=en-us")
        options.AddArgument("--window-size=400,700")
        options.AddAdditionalChromeOption("useAutomationExtension", False)
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", False)
        service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        driver = New ChromeDriver(service, options)
    End Sub
```

All together:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Public Class Step1
    Public Shared driver As ChromeDriver
    Public Shared options As ChromeOptions
    Public Shared service As ChromeDriverService
    Public Sub New()

        
        If driver isnot nothing then return

        options = New ChromeOptions
        options.AddArgument("--lang=en-us")
        options.AddArgument("--window-size=400,700")
        options.AddAdditionalChromeOption("useAutomationExtension", False)
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", False)
        service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        driver = New ChromeDriver(service, options)
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartNavigate()
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/")
    End Sub
End Class
```